# Wordpress Â and â€Â removing strange chars / character-encoding

Tags: php, wordpress, character-encoding

I have found several forms with this question but they are at least 5 years old and the answers did not work for today.

I am having an issue with these chras that show up, mainly in Explorer or Safari but not firefox. Any ideas how to fix them?

Here is the website for viewing in explore: http://timstaples.com/?p=blog&id=7

Not sure if its a "database issue" or a "chars" issue.

Comment: BTW: It looks perfect in chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server is not sending the charset in the `Content-Type` header and the HTML meta fallback is broken:

```
<meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=UTF-8″>
```

Note the invalid curly quotes instead of straight quotes.

That means there's no valid declaration for what encoding the page is in and hence the browser takes a guess. Some guess wrong.

See [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).

Comment: My friend @deceze, you are brilliant! That worked. It was simply the "quotes" in my meta Content-Type tags. It simply did a search and replace all of them and it worked. Wow, you saved me so much time. Blessings to you amigo! May you be rewarded abundantly! :)